# Deedle 1.0.7 Frame row indexing doesn't enforce unique key

Tags: indexing, f#, duplicates, deedle

Since Deedle 1.0.7 release the index row function no longer validate whether the column being used as the key contain unique value. This behaviour is different what the comments suggest. How can I ensure only unique value can be used as the column key?

In the previous version the following code will trigger errors as the column being used as the index contain duplicates. However in Deedle 1.0.7 this no longer is the case, the code will work and frame will contain 1 index entry pointing to an array of records. is this by design?

```
type t1 = {d:DateTime; v:double}

let s1 =[{d=DateTime.Now.Date; v= 1.0};
          {d=DateTime.Now.Date; v= 2.0};
          {d=DateTime.Now.Date; v= 3.0};
         ]

let f1 = Frame.ofRecords s1 |> Frame.indexRowsDate "d"


 type t2 = {d:int; v:double}

 let s2 =[{d=1; v= 1.0};
          {d=1; v= 2.0};
           {d=1; v= 3.0};
         ]

 let f2 = Frame.ofRecords s2 |> Frame.indexRowsInt "d"
```

However if I try to access the series indexed by duplicate key Deedle will give an error

```
let cv = f2.GetColumn<double> "v"

let item = cv.Get(1)

val cv : Series<int,double> = series [ 1 => 1; 1 => 2; 1 => 3]

> 
System.ArgumentException: Duplicate key '1'. Duplicate keys are not     allowed in the index.
 Parameter name: keys
   at Deedle.Indices.Linear.LinearIndex`1.makeLookup() in     c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Indices\LinearIndex.fs:line 53
```

at Deedle.Indices.Linear.LinearIndex`1.get_lookupMap() in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Indices\LinearIndex.fs:line 63
   at Deedle.Indices.Linear.LinearIndex`1.Deedle-Indices-IIndex`1-Locate(K key) in c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Indices\LinearIndex.fs:line 101
   at Deedle.Series`2.Get(K key) in    c:\Tomas\Public\Deedle\src\Deedle\Series.fs:line 291
       at .$FSI_0046.main@() in C:\Users\win8dev\Documents\Visual Studio    2013\Projects\DeedleTake2\Deedle107\Script.fsx:line 40
     Stopped due to error

Update:

As suggested by Tomas a Github ticket has been raised

https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/issues/294

Comment: I think we should ensure that the keys are unique in Deedle. Can you please log an issue (with the code here) on GitHub, so that we can recover the original (intended) behavior?

Comment: Ticket raised on GitHub. Thanks